# How can I fix this bug that is causing my app to crash on other's phones, if it isn't crashing on mine, and I have no way of seeing what's going on?

Tags: android, debugging, nullpointerexception, crash-reports, oncreate

In order to get my feet wet with Android development, I thought I'd hire a guy to lay the foundation of a simple app for me, then I would try and take it from there. So far it's worked really well. I've been able to learn quite a bit.

One of the issues I am having though is that I keep getting crash reports about an bug that is causing the app to crash, but the app works perfectly for me on my Nexus S! I am used to iOS development where everything is uniform...

A number of reports are coming in with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elan.readerJapanese/com.elan.readerJapanese.Language}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.elan.readerJapanese.Language.onCreate(Language.java:91)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
 ... 11 more'
```

Which is pretty hard for me to understand. I understand that there is a null pointer exception being thrown in my language class's onCreate method, but I can't get it to reproduce! So I have no idea what may be going on. Here is the code for my onCreate method. `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.title_list_menu);
   me=this;

   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   DatabaseHelper myDatabaseAdapter;
    myDatabaseAdapter = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(me);
   if(extras !=null)
   {


    if(!myDatabaseAdapter.databaseReady()){
        try{
            myDatabaseAdapter.copyDatabase2();
            DatabaseHelper_Spa myDatabaseAdapter_spa = DatabaseHelper_Spa.getInstance(me);
            myDatabaseAdapter_spa.copyDatabaseSpanish2();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myDatabaseAdapter.databaseReady();
    }
   }else{
        //myDatabaseAdapter.close();
       if(!myDatabaseAdapter.databaseReady()){
            try{
                myDatabaseAdapter.copyDatabase2();
                DatabaseHelper_Spa myDatabaseAdapter_spa = DatabaseHelper_Spa.getInstance(me);
                myDatabaseAdapter_spa.copyDatabaseSpanish2();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myDatabaseAdapter.databaseReady();
        }
       else if(myDatabaseAdapter.getSaveVerse()[0]!=null||!myDatabaseAdapter.getSaveVerse()[0].equals("")){
            String data[]=myDatabaseAdapter.getSaveVerse();
           Intent intent=new Intent(Language.this,  Verse.class);
        intent.putExtra("language",data[0]);
        intent.putExtra("volume_id",data[1]);
        intent.putExtra("chapter",data[2]);
        intent.putExtra("book",data[3]);
        intent.putExtra("book_id",data[4]);
        intent.putExtra("multiple_languages",false);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }


  // listImage=new Bitmap[]{BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sharing),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.contact_us),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.about)};
   m_orders = new ArrayList<SettingsObject>();
   this.m_adapter = new AboutAdapter(this, R.layout.language_row, m_orders);
   setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
   viewOrders = new Runnable(){
       @Override
       public void run() {
           getOrders();
       }
   };

   Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
   thread.start();
```

}`

It would be great if someone could tell me if they see something out of line in the above code, or if not,m what I can do to try and debug this error. Like I said, I am having trouble with it because the error won't reproduce on my device, so it's hard to see what people are getting.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you point out where in your code the exception is happening?

Comment: Hi Nicklas, that is the reason for this question. I really don't know where the exception is occurring, namely because I can't get it to happen on my device... Also, I don't really have a lot of experience with Android, so the exception might be right in front of me, and I'm just not seeing it. I was hoping more sets of eyes could help out

Comment: But you have a line number in the exception, line 91
It's happening on Language.java:91

Comment: It says right there, line 91, which one is that? `at com.elan.readerJapanese.Language.onCreate(Language.java:91)`

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't know how I missed that. Line 91 is this line String data[]=myDatabaseAdapter.getSaveVerse();
Which definitely gives me a place where I can start looking for more clues as to what is going on. I'm still perplexed as to why it only crashes on some devices, and works great on others

Comment: It may be an issue with using different locales and languages.  Try switching your language to Japanese (or English, whichever you are not using) on your phone/emulator.

Comment: Also, try to uninstall the app and remove all resources on the SDCard if there are any, sometimes your installed app might be in a state that doesn't trigger the crash. But otherwise this is stuff you have to deal with, the market is very fragmented and different devices work differently (sadly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace you see that the exception occured at line 91 in Language.java.

You can tell this from the last part of the exception output:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.elan.readerJapanese.Language.onCreate(Language.java:91)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
... 11 more'
```

Without knowing the line I would guess it has something to do with the database stuff.
Could the method `getSaveVerse` ever return null?

---

I'm guessing your line number have changed since that stack trace because if line 91 is the one that you say the only that could cause that stack trace is if `myDatabaseAdapter` is null but that would make the line before (`else if(myDatabaseAdapter.getSaveVerse()[0]!=null||!myDatabaseAdapter.getSaveVerse()[0].equals("")){`) to crash.

I don't see how it's possible for that stack trace to occur unless you have some other object modifying `myDatabaseAdapter`

That said make sure that your `DatabaseHelper` doesn't modify your Activity

Comment: I think you nailed it right on the head. I'll go in there and make sure that it can't return null. Thanks!!

Comment: Or rather make sure it <i>can</i> return null and check for a null value in your code. Right now I must always return an array who's size is always at least 1.

Comment: A very fine point indeed! I'll keep poking around, and see what I can find. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, good luck. Keep us updated, any information might help someone else in the future :)